# How limited is support for Level 4 in Safari Content Blockers?

Tags: safari, css-selectors, safari-content-blocker

Back in 2015 when Safari Content Blockers were released it was said that they support CSS Selectors Level 4 expressions.

However even today they don't support at least the `:has()` operator.

**What parts of Level4-only specification does Safari actually supports?**

Is this the only what is supported (per [Webkit blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/3615/css-selectors-inside-selectors-discover-matches-not-and-nth-child/)):

`:matches()`, `:not()`, `:nth-child()`, and `:nth-last-child()`?

Answer (score 1):

Safari 9, released in 2015, shipped with [support for the following level 4 selectors](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW34):

- Case insensitive attribute selectors, e.g. `[type="text" i]`
- [`:any-link`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-any-link-pseudo)
- [Level 4 `:lang()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-lang-pseudo)
- [Level 4 `:not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#negation)
- [`:matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#matches)
- [Level 4 `:nth-child(An+B of S)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo) (implied likewise for `:nth-last-child()`)
- [`:placeholder-shown`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#placeholder)

As of 2018, no new level 4 selectors have been added since. However, Safari remains the only browser to support all but the first and last of these.

There are no known browser implementations of `:has()`, and frankly I wouldn't hold out on one surfacing within the next few years. Given that browser implementations are optimized for matching CSS selectors live, implementing snapshot matching is going to take a non-trivial amount of work which doesn't seem to be work vendors want to invest effort into right now. The WG is still exploring their options in the performance department.

Comment: Thanks for elaborate answer! Is there any issue tracker or discussion board open to external developers which could allow tracking prospects of implementing `:has()` in future versions of Safari?

Comment: @wass rubleff: There aren't any open issues on bugs.webkit.org but you might start there.

Comment: Is it an appropriate way to ask for the prospects of supporting for elements of a new standard?

Comment: @wass rubleff: Hmm, on second thought I don't believe so. Issue trackers aren't suited to discussing the prospects so much as tracking the actual development of features.